# How to convert xml to .json file in java

Tags: java, xml, json

```
  public class ConvertXMLtoJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream in =             ConvertXMLtoJSON.class.getResourceAsStream("D:\\sample.xml");
        String xml = IOUtils.toString(in);
        XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
        JSON json = xmlSerializer.read(xml);  
        System.out.println(json.toString(2));
    }
      }
```

but i am getting error

```
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1020)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:358)
at com.apache.poi.ConvertXMLtoJSON.main(ConvertXMLtoJSON.java:13
```

can u please help me to resolve it
This is my xml format
             
       
        ac3
        AC3 Phone
        ACME
        phone
        200.0 
        1.0 
        true

i have generated this xml from my excel file and i have convert this xml file to json file

Comment: What library/-ies are you using? POI? What kind of input XML, output JSON? Too vague a question without more info.

Comment: Hi Durga, Can you please either select the correct answer which resolved your issue or add your answer if you have managed to resolve this of your own? I am also getting the same error and not finding the answers given here useful for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code which is used to convert xml to json

```
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.XML;
 import java.io.*;


 public class ConvertXMLtoJSON2{  
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        String fileName = "D:\\temp.json";
        try {           
            File file = new File ("D:\\output333.xml");  
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);  
            StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();  
            int ptr = 0;  
            while ((ptr = inputStream.read()) != -1 ) {  
                builder.append((char) ptr); 
              //  System.out.println(ptr);
            }  

            String xml  = builder.toString();  
            JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);   
            // System.out.println(jsonObj.toString()); 
            // System.out.println(jsonObj.toString().split(",").length);
            // Assume default encoding.
            FileWriter fileWriter =
                new FileWriter(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            // Always close files.

            for(int i= 0 ;i < jsonObj.toString().split(",").length; i ++) {
               System.out.println(jsonObj.toString().split(",")[i]);
               bufferedWriter.write(jsonObj.toString().split(",")[i]);
               bufferedWriter.write("\n");
            }

            bufferedWriter.close();
        }


            /* 
            String xmlString  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ASF_Service_ResponseVO id=\"1\"><service type=\"String\">OnboardingV2</service><operation type=\"String\">start_onboarding_session</operation><requested_version type=\"String\">1.0</requested_version><actual_version type=\"String\">1.0</actual_version><server_info type=\"String\">onboardingv2serv:start_onboarding_session&CalThreadId=85&TopLevelTxnStartTime=13b40fe91c4&Host=L-BLR-00438534&pid=3564</server_info><result type=\"Onboarding::StartOnboardingSessionResponse\" id=\"2\"><onboarding_id type=\"String\">137</onboarding_id><success type=\"bool\">true</success></result></ASF_Service_ResponseVO>"; 

            JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);  
            System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());  
            */
          catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Error writing to file '"
                    + fileName + "'");
                // Or we could just do this:
                // ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to read physical `File` as a classpath `Resource`, which is **wrong**

```
InputStream in = ConvertXMLtoJSON.class.getResourceAsStream("D:\\sample.xml");
```

Change it to

```
InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\sample.xml"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i got the solution my file is getting converted to .json

Answer (score 3):

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString(in);
```

Here InputStream `in` is null so it raise `NullPointerException`.

`Class#getResourceAsStream(String name)` it use to load resource from classpath and normally use in web-based project, and an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:

1. If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
2. Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
   modified_package_name/name

As [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

As your file exists in local hard-drive(`D:\\sample.xml`) better use `FileInputStream` to load the resouce.

```
InputStream in =  new FileInputStream("D:\\sample.xml");
```

Find a good related question  -

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import java.io.*;

public class ConverterXMLToJSON {
    public static int PRETTY_FACTOR=4;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jsonFileName = "src\\main\\resources\\Light.json";
        try {
            File xmlFile = new File("src\\main\\resources\\Light.xml");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int ptr;
            while ((ptr = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                builder.append((char) ptr);
            }

            String xml = builder.toString();
            JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
            System.out.print(jsonObj);
            FileWriter fileWriter =
                    new FileWriter(jsonFileName);

            // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                    new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferedWriter.write(jsonObj.toString(PRETTY_FACTOR));
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error writing to file '"
                            + jsonFileName + "'");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can convert xml to json. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Dzg)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class JsonConversion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String xmlString  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ASF_Service_ResponseVO id=\"1\"><service type=\"String\">OnboardingV2</service>"
        + "<operation type=\"String\">start_onboarding_session</operation><requested_version type=\"String\">1.0</requested_version>"
        + "<actual_version type=\"String\">1.0</actual_version><server_info type=\"String\">onboardingv2serv:start_onboarding_session"
        + "&amp;CalThreadId=85&amp;TopLevelTxnStartTime=13b40fe91c4&amp;Host=L-BLR-00438534&amp;pid=3564</server_info><result type="
        + "\"Onboarding::StartOnboardingSessionResponse\" id=\"2\"><onboarding_id type=\"String\">137</onboarding_id><success type="
        + "\"bool\">true</success></result></ASF_Service_ResponseVO>"; 

        String json = U.xmlToJson(xmlString);  
        System.out.println(json);  
    }
}
```